# I have a set of Sub () in VBA. I would like write a code which sets a priority levels, which subs should be run as first and which afterwards

Tags: excel, vba

I have a set of Sub (). I would like write a code which sets a priority levels. For example Sub Start() should be run as first and Sub Input () as second and Sub End() as last.

I am more familiar with such coding in MS Access. here is an example what I am usually using:

```
Public Sub executeAnalysis()
'Turns off the Access warning messages´
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
'Turns on the hourglass
DoCmd.Hourglass True

'Runs the analysis
DoCmd.OpenQuery "Q001_DateCreation"
DoCmd.OpenQuery "Q001a_Insert_N0"
DoCmd.OpenQuery "Q002_WithoutRejections"
DoCmd.OpenQuery "Q003_GroupByFirstDate"
DoCmd.OpenQuery "Q004_Duration"
DoCmd.OpenQuery "Q005_InTime"
DoCmd.OpenQuery "Q006_OnlyMatl"
DoCmd.OpenQuery "Q007_CPOs"
DoCmd.OpenQuery "Q008_GroupByMatl"


'Turns off the hourglass
DoCmd.Hourglass False
'Turns the Access warning messages back on
DoCmd.SetWarnings True

'Msg Box when finished
MsgBox "Finished Analysis!"


End Sub
```

I would be grateful for your help!

Cheers I_K_M

Answer (score 1):

As with any other MS product that has VBA support, Excel will execute the code in the order given in your program (considering flow-control constructs, of course). So the only thing you should do is write the calls to each sub in the order you want to call them:

```
public sub executeStuff()
    call mySub_start()
    call mySub_whatGoesNext()
    call mySub_finish()
end sub
```

As you can see, it is exactly what you would do with Access objects.

You can, of course, set some conditions to define if a particular procedure is called or not. A simple example:

```
public sub executeStuff()
    call mySub_start()
    if ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = 10 then
        call mySub_doThis()
    else
        call mySub_doThat()
    end if
    call mySub_finish()
end sub
```

Comment: @I_K_M happy to help (if you think it solves your question, accept it ;) )

Answer (score 0):

That is really simple code. But that is the way how I did it!!!

Private Sub Analysis_Click()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Runs the analysis
    Call Formatting
    Call Rename
    Call SumIFF
    Call ArrayIFF
    Call CW
    Call Status
    Call OpenValue
    Call Country
    Call check
    Call Removeformulas
    Call text

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

'Msg Box when finished
MsgBox "Finished Analysis!"
End Sub